# How to use elastic search for advanced queries:

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch. I'm already pretty deep into it but I'm very confused as to how to go about writing advanced queries. There are queries / filters / etc. I'm confused as to how to proceed.

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
photos: {people: [{person_id: 1, person_name:"john kealy"}], 
         tags: [{tag_id: 1, tag_name:"other tag"}, 
         by_line: "John D Kealy/My website.com",
         location: "Some Place OUt West"]
```

I need to be able to string together these queries dynamically ALWAYS pulling in FULL MATCHES, e.g. I would like to search for

people.person_id: [1,2] (pulls in only photos with BOTH or more peole)
tags.tag_id: [1,2,3] (pulls in only photos with all three or more tags)
by_line: "John D. Kealy/My Website.com" (the full name including the slash)
location: "some place out west"

I would like to write one query with all these items. I need to include the slash in "by_line", i don't care up upper or lower case. I need the exact match "some place out west". What do I use here? Queries or filters / filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General guidelines for bool filters/queries can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html).

If you are constructing an "exact match" query, you can often use the [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) filter (or query).

If you are constructing a search that requires a solid performance speed wise, a [filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) is often advisable, as filters are set before the query is run, often improving performance.

As for your specific example, the below filters should work, throw it around a matchAll query or anything else you need [With the non-analyzed by_line field, the analyzed one has a query). This should give you an idea as how to construct future queries:

**NOTE**: This assumes that your by_line field is not analyzed. The double slash will escape your slash delimiter, if you are using an analyzed field you must use a match query.

**Without analyzer on by_line**

```
{
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : {
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                { "terms" : {"people.person_id" : ["1", "2"]}}, 
                { "terms" : {"tags.tag_id" : ["1", "2", "3"]}},
                { "term" : {"by_line" : "John D. Kealy\\/My Website.com"}}, 
                { "term" : {"location" : "some place out west"}}
              ]
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I will keep the above there for future readers, however I see in your post history that you are using the standard analyzer, your query should be structured as follows.

**With analyzer on by_line**

```
{
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : {
         "query": {
            "match": {
               "by_line": "John Kealy/BFA.com"
             }
         },
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                { "terms" : {"people.person_id" : ["1", "2"]}}, 
                { "terms" : {"tags.tag_id" : ["1", "2", "3"]}},
                { "term" : {"location" : "some place out west"}}
              ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much Daniel. Follow-up question, how do I know to use location or by_line in the query field?  There's a change my location field could have a slash too

Comment: And would there be any issue with using fquery and splitting on the empty space ? this seems to work too 
{filtered:
  {filter:
    {and:
      [{term: {is_visible:true}}, 
       {term: {is_private:false}}, 
       {fquery: {query:{match:{by_line:"JohnKealy"}}}},
       {fquery: {query:{match:{by_line:"/MyWebsite.com"}}}}]}}}

Comment: Regarding your first question, if there is a slash and you use the standard analyzer, you would need to use a match query for that as well (as multimatch or a [filter query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html)). Using fquery is just fine, all fquery does is give a syntax for Elasticsearch to name the filter so it can be cached, which is great if you use the filter on many queries. Edit: So you are running those match queries as a filter, the field must match both of them. They are query filters and thus slower than term filters.